# How do i initialize an array only once #c

Tags: c#, arrays

```
char array[4] = {'1','1','1','1'}
.....
array[0] = 3
array = {'3','1','1','1'}
```

However, when it loops again, values reset back to 1,1,1,1

How do i keep the 3 there?

As the question states, how do initialize an array only once?

As i plan to use the array to keep track of some values in a do while loop, every time it loops again, the values get reset to 1,1,1,1. How do i only make sure that it is set to 1,1,1,1 ONCE and when it enters the loop again, whatever value that was changed STAYS and not get reset to 1,1,1,1 again.

Thanks!

Comment: Declare and initialize the array outside of the loop?

Comment: To initialize array only once you need to initialize array only once... Possibly your actual code initializes array multiple times (i.e. each loop iteration) - or to be more precise re-creates array referenced by variable of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of a loop iteration, `array` goes out of scope. When you initialize `array` in the next iteration, it creates a completely new char[] in memory.

If you wish to keep the value of array, you need to do two things:

1. Only initialize it once (i.e. set it to {'1','1','1','1'} once)
2. Keep it in scope across iterations - i.e. declare it outside of the loop (above it, of course).